# Google play infinite login loop

Tags: google-play-store

I recently changed my Google password, but now when I open Google Play and Gmail, it prompts me for my password and won't accept it. It works in the YouTube app only. I've tried rebooting, but this has been going on for about a week, so I don't think its a google server issue.

Device: NVidia Shield with Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove your Google account from accounts and add it again. I also had this problem, but removing&adding it again solved it instantly.

It will sync with Gmail, Contacts again, so you should have no problems

Comment: Now Play Services crashes every time I add the account

Comment: Try to delete Play Services cache. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Find Google Play Services app, click on it, find Delete data/clear cache. Reboot device and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote it but I don't have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

ITS YOUR PHONE!  It's not a Google issue, as I'd suspected.  No amount of adding and replacing google accounts will work.  I've been battling this issue for a year and doing everything everyone/anyone suggests to no avail.  Except resetting phone to factory defaults... that was too scary so I didn't do that.  I recently had to replace my phone for a faulty internal (non-replaceable) battery, and HELLO the new phone allows me to sign in without any issues.  It's a miracle.  BTW, old phone is HTC One M9, and Verizon replacement phone is a Samsung Galaxy s7 (new is s9, don't care, it works). The problem is with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You go to apps and clear data and cache from Google apps in Google play / Google services and services framework and remove any accounts currently on Android. Then go to backup in settings and add account this backup rout re login to account without loop

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Removing the account is not always going to work if you've synced your device more than once due to such things as a re-flash or a re-build of the device. In my case it was a *HTC One A9* phone. I recently had to reflash my phone and I stupidly added two accounts to my phone instead of leaving it as a *single account*, but I was able to use Google apps (gmail, drive, etc) using multiple accounts. Go figure.
So I did this:

- Go to your device Settings
- Don't go to Google option, but to Accounts and Sync
- Click on an account
- Click the three dots on the top-right
- Delete or Remove the account. Do this for every account you may have there.
- Re-boot the phone/device
- Re-add your primary Google account that you want associated with the device for Google Play, Google Services, etc...
- Make sure everything is ok. Now for the final steps
- Go to Settings on your phone again
- This time go to Google option -> Accounts
- You may be asked to verify who you are again. Do that. I had to recover my security codes for cases when you loose your password
- Now your Google account should show you the usual Google Account options - Home | Personal Info | Data & Personalisation etc etc

You should be ok from there. Just don't add another G account to the device. Only add them through the G apps.